# How to get DIV from CefSharp?

Tags: javascript, c#, chromium, cefsharp

I try to get some DIV by JS script executed in CefSharp and then proced it in C# code. If I geting plain text I can got this from Cef to C# code, but if I try to get whole DIV I got null- this is a issue.

I prepared two JS to get DIV, and string from webpage by css selector. I tested this in Chrome web browser on 4programmers.net page.

JS's:

`document.querySelector("#entry-140680").querySelector(".microblog-text").innerText` - this return some tekst in console

`document.querySelector("#entry-140680")` - this return some DIV with childs nodes.

and the result:

[result of script in chrome console window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rCiF.png)

Then I prepared C# code to execute above JS on CefSharp:

```
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
#if ANYCPU
            //Only required for PlatformTarget of AnyCPU
            CefRuntime.SubscribeAnyCpuAssemblyResolver();
#endif

            const string testUrl = "4programmers.net";

            AsyncContext.Run(async delegate
            {
                var settings = new CefSettings()
                {
                    //By default CefSharp will use an in-memory cache, you need to specify a Cache Folder to persist data
                    CachePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "CefSharp\\Cache")
                };

                // Create the CefSharp.OffScreen.ChromiumWebBrowser instance
                using (var browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(testUrl))
                {
                    var initialLoadResponse = await browser.WaitForInitialLoadAsync();

                    if (!initialLoadResponse.Success)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(string.Format("Page load failed with ErrorCode:{0}, HttpStatusCode:{1}", initialLoadResponse.ErrorCode, initialLoadResponse.HttpStatusCode));
                    }

                    //Give the browser a little time to render
                    await Task.Delay(10000);

                    await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("window.scrollTo(0,800);");

                    await Task.Delay(10000);

                    await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.querySelector(\"#entry-140680\").querySelector(\".microblog-text\").innerText").ContinueWith(x =>
                    {
                        var response = x.Result;

                        if (response.Success && response.Result != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(response.Result == null ? "NULL" : response.Result.ToString());
                        }
                    });

                    Console.WriteLine("--------------");

                    await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.querySelector(\"#entry-140680\")").ContinueWith(x =>
                    {
                        var response = x.Result;

                        if (response.Success)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(response.Result == null?"NULL":response.Result.ToString());
                        }
                    });
                }

                Cef.Shutdown();
            });

            return 0;
        }
```

and the output:

```
Dziś kilka słów o konferencjach. W dużym skrócie. Jak chcecie Home Office, to zapomnijcie o starych dobrych konferencjach.

https://koziolekweb.pl/2024/02/22/home-office-a-sprawa-konferencji/

#koziolekweb #autopromocja
--------------
NULL
```

**How can I get DIV as object, JSON, string from CefSharp?**

Comment: You cannot directly return a DOM element, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#2-how-do-you-call-a-javascript-method-that-returns-a-result for more information. Alternatively [CefSharp.Dom](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.Dom?tab=readme-ov-file#cefsharpdom-formerly-cefsharppuppeteer) provides a DOM API